# Unit Testing - Controller not picking up value from mocked IConfiguration in ASP.NET Core Web API Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to Unit Test my Login Action in ASP.NET Core Web API with mock services, all the mocking works fine but when I try to Mock my `IConfiguration` file the controller does not pick up the value from it.

Here's my Unit testing code that calls my controller action:

```
[Fact]
public async Task SignInTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var requestVM = new CustomerSignInRequestVM
    {
        EmailPhone = "03026993900",
        RegNum = "Abc123"
    };

    var config = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
    //HERE I AM SETTING ALL MY CONFIGURATION VALUES TO RETURN SOME FAKE VALUES

    //config.Setup(cf => cf.GetSection("Jwt:Encryptionkey").Value).Returns("01 02 03");    
    config.Setup(x => x.GetSection("Jwt:Encryptionkey").Value).Returns("abc");
    config.Setup(x => x.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Value).Returns("test.com");
    config.Setup(x => x.GetSection("Jwt:ExpiryTimeInMinutes").Value).Returns("Jwt:ExpiryTimeInMinutes");   

    //THIS MOCKING WORK FINE IN CONTROLLER ACTION
    var customerApplication = new Mock<ICustomerApplication>();
    customerApplication.Setup(app => app.GetCustomer(It.IsAny<SignIn>())).ReturnsAsync(GetCustomerMockData);

    var claimApplication = new Mock<IClaimApplication>();
    claimApplication.Setup(app => app.GetListByRole(It.IsAny<ApplicationRole>())).ReturnsAsync(new List<ApplicationClaim> { new ApplicationClaim { Active = true, ClaimCode = "AUC_GA", ClaimLabel = "Auction.GetAll" } });

    //I'm also injecting my IConfiguration object here in my controller setup

    var controller = new CustomerController(customerApplication.Object, null, claimApplication.Object, null, null, config.Object, null);

    // Act
    var response = await controller.SignIn(requestVM, new CancellationToken());
    var okObjectResult = response as OkObjectResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(200, okObjectResult.StatusCode);
}
```

but when I try to retrieve values from **injected** `IConfiguration` service inside my controller action like this:

`var Issuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],`

this returns `null` to me, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You setup `x.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Value` yet call `Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]`. Those are two different things. You are better off building an in-memory configuration that has all its desired functionality than trying to mock everything correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You setup `x.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Value` yet call `Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]`. Those are two different things and will result in the stated issue.

You are better off building an in-memory configuration that has all its desired functionality than trying to mock everything correctly.

```
//...

var fakeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Jwt:Encryptionkey", "abc"},
    {"Jwt:Issuer", "test.com"},
    {"Jwt:ExpiryTimeInMinutes", "some value"}
};

IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(fakeValues)
    .Build();

//...

var controller = new CustomerController(customerApplication.Object, null, 
        claimApplication.Object, null, null, config, null);

//...
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot this works and serves the purpose! :) Cheers